# Fluently.Configure throws "Database was not configured through Database method" exception

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to get an in-house application up and running for debugging and when I start the solution, it fails calling the Fluently.Configure() method. Digging into the exception, I see the potential reason as "Database was not configured through Database method."

```
 public static ISessionFactory IdCardSessionFactoryWeb
    {
        get
        {
            if (_idCardSessionFactoryWeb != null) return _idCardSessionFactoryWeb;
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
            {
                x.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString; 
                x.Driver<SybaseAdoNet4Driver>();
                x.Dialect<SybaseAdoNet4Dialect>();
                x.Batcher<SybaseASEBatcherFactory>();
            });


            _idCardSessionFactoryWeb = Fluently.Configure(cfg)
                .ExposeConfiguration(c => c
                    .SetInterceptor(new ABCInterceptor())
                    .SetProperty(Environment.ShowSql, "true")
                    .SetProperty(Environment.WrapResultSets, "true")
                    .SetProperty("command_timeout", timeout)
                    .SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web"))
                .Mappings(m =>
                    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Batch>())
                .BuildSessionFactory();
            return _idCardSessionFactoryWeb;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed to update the nuget package, and then restart my solution.